# TSP optimal tour

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, graph

I wrote a bacterial evolutionary algorithm to solve TSP problems. I chose XQF131 instance (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/vlsi/index.html) to test my algorithm.
This problem was solved by Concorde, and the optimal tour is 564. But I calculated the shown optimal tour 's length and it is 567,2029.(http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/vlsi/xqf131.tour.html)
With my algorithm I found a better solution 566,4142.
My question is: how Concorde algorithm works? It calculates the optimal solution or approximation?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Are your calculations correct? If the literature says 564, it's unlikely they made a mistake that hasn't been spotted until now. Are you absolutely sure their tour is longer than they claim?

Comment: I calculated the optimal tour of an other instance (ch130). And my calculated value is equal with the given value. So I suppose that my calculation is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you computed the distances correctly ? It seems that you should be getting an integer distance. Indeed, from the website you cite, "In these examples, the cost of travel between cities is specified by the Euclidean distance rounded to the nearest whole number".

Hopefully, your algorithm still discovered an optimal solution...

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde_TSP_Solver), [this](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/concorde/implement.shtml) page and the wording on the site you posted, what you linked to is supposed to be the optimal tour, not an approximation and Concorde is supposed to give optimal solutions.

I would check my calculations to make sure they did indeed make a mistake when reporting the length. If yes, you can probably publish this.

Even if not, your algorithm is probably only very slightly worse. If it is faster than Concorde or at least better than other evolutionary methods, you can probably still publish something.

Good job and good luck!